# Own matrix multiplication implementation with MPI Send/Recv

Tags: c, mpi

I tried to write a function called *matrixMultiply* that simply takes two 4 x 4 matrices called a and b, multiplies them and stores the result in the 4 x 4 matrix c. After this I wanted to expand the program into a more general one, for n x n matrices. Sadly the program compiles but gets stuck while executing it. I would be very thankful about someone of you being able to tell me where my error is.

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import "mpi.h"

void matrixMultiply(int argc, char* argv[], int a[][4], int b[][4], int c[][4])
{
    int n = 4;
    int procs;
    int rank;
    int rootRank = 0;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if(rank == rootRank) {
        int current_row[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            int current_column[4];
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

                //getting the i-th row
                for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    current_row[k] = a[i][k];
                }

                //getting the j-th column
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                {
                    current_column[k] = b[k][j];
                }

                //MPI_Send(void* data, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int destination, int tag, MPI_Comm communicator)
                MPI_Bsend(current_row, 4, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Bsend(current_column, 4, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

                int result;
                //MPI_Recv(void* data, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int source, int tag, MPI_Comm communicator, MPI_Status* status)
                MPI_Recv(&result, 1, MPI_INT, i ,2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                c[i][j]=result;
            }
        }

        /* this code is only used to check the resulting matrix c*/
        printf("c:\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                printf("%d ", c[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    else {
        int result = 0;
        int local_row[4] = {0,0,0,0};
        int local_column[4] = {2,2,2,2};

        //MPI_Recv(void* data, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int source, int tag, MPI_Comm communicator, MPI_Status* status)
        MPI_Recv(local_row, 4, MPI_INT, rootRank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(local_column, 4, MPI_INT, rootRank, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            result+= local_row[i] * local_column[i];
        }

        //MPI_Send(void* data, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int destination, int tag, MPI_Comm communicator)
        MPI_Bsend(&result, 1, MPI_INT, rootRank, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int d[][4] = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
    int e[][4] = {{16,15,14,13}, {12,11,10,9}, {8,7,6,5}, {4,3,2,1}};
    int f[][4] = {{0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}};

    matrixMultiply(argc, argv, d, e, f);

}
```

Comment: please trim your code (e.g. make it a [MCVE]). Generally speaking, `MPI_Bsend()` is evil and you should consider an other approach. Also, please state how many MPI tasks you are running.

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues to address:

`MPI_Bsend` (as opposed to `MPI_Send`) requires a preceding call to `MPI_Buffer_attach`.  See the notes here: https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Bsend.html or any recent version of the MPI spec.

Try with that change first.  It's possible that's enough to get it going.  If not, double check any ordering of Sends and Receives, considered globally, to see whether there's a deadlock anywhere in the system.

As an aside, you may be able to improve performance as well as avoiding some deadlock scenarios by switching to nonblocking sends and receives (`MPI_Isend`, `MPI_Irecv` and related) and completing them via `MPI_Waitall`, `MPI_Testall` or similar after they've all initiated.  This would be more similar to how MPI implementations typically execute collective operations under the hood - which could also have performance benefits over making individual send and receive calls, due to the implementation knowing more about the hardware and what's going on under the hood and being able to optimize ordering around that.  What you're doing looks something like an `MPI_Bcast` followed by an `MPI_Gather`, as one possible alternative pattern that would lean more heavily on the implementation to take care of optimizations for you.